# Remove Content Control when Text is edited programmatically

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.contentcontrol.temporary.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> If the Temporary property is true, **the ContentControl is automatically deleted** when the user types in the control, or **when the text in the control is changed programmatically**. When the ContentControl is automatically deleted from the document, the text in the control remains in the document.

It's working for "when the user types in the control" using Word Editor, but not when I change Text in (C#) code. My code is as below.

1. Make a tag Temporary

   ```
   static void MakeTagsTemporary(List<Tag> tagList)
   {
       tagList.ForEach(x => x.Parent.Append(new TemporarySdt() { Val = true }));
   } mainPart.Document.Save();
   ```

   I am saving specifically to accept changes of making the Content Control Temporary, but with no effect.
2. Edit the text

   ```
   static void ApplyProductGrid(MainDocumentPart mainPart, Plan pl, List<Tag> tagList)
   {
       foreach (Tag tagitem in tagList)
       {
           string GridValue = pl.FormattedTags.Where(x => x.Key == tagitem.Val).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
           tagitem.Parent.Parent.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault().Text = GridValue;
       }
   }
   ```

The line `tagitem.Parent.Parent.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault().Text = GridValue;` is doing its job, its updating the value but Content Control is not removed.

When I edit something from word, Content Control is getting deleted.